# after_validation find existing record's id in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, model

I'm fairly new to Ruby on Rails and within my app the user is able to create a 'build' record that will only be saved if the entire record is unique. If a user tries to create an existing 'build' / record and the validation fails, I need to be able to redirect that user to the existing record.

As I have stated, I am a novice and made a valiant attempt at using the parameters passed to my create action as so:

```
    def create

    @build = Build.new(params[:build])

    if @build.save
        redirect_to :action => 'view', :id => @build.id 
    else
        @bexist = Build.find(params[:build])
        redirect_to :action => 'view', :id => @bexist.id
    end

end
```

Clearly this isn't correct... I also tried to look into callbacks with after_validation, but wasn't sure how to access or even store the existing record's id. Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the attribute/value hash to be passed as the :conditions option, and you need to specify *:first*, *:last*, or *:all* as the first argument.

```
@bexist = Build.find(:first, :conditions => params[:build])
```

Alternatively, you can use the *#first* method instead of using *#find* with a *:first* argument.

```
@bexist = Build.first(:conditions => params[:build])
```

In Rails 3, you have yet another option...

```
@bexist = Build.where(params[:build]).first
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I've been going crazy trying to figure this one out, and of course it turns out to be really simple. Thanks!